# System new line separator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, newline

How can I determine new line separator used by OS (LF, CR/LF or other), in Ruby?

Comment: Why do you need this info? What's your use case?

Comment: I'm writing sort of object-oriented framework for working with files and want to get rid of such legacy problems as "text/binary mode", "charset conversion when FTP-ing" etc. I have decided that it's better to perform all operations in binary mode and that caused a small problem with "MyFile.puts" method. The function is intended to write new line separator at the end of the line and the separator should be one the most expected by the user of the framework.

Comment: That seems like it could be very problematic. Better not to reinvent the file handling that the language already gives you. Ruby already *has* an OO framework for dealing with files...

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't found it... I need something like this: `File.new("abc.txt", "some content").copy_to(Directory['C:\Temp']).copy_to(RemoteDirectory[credentials, '/']).rename("def.txt")`. Does Ruby have something like that?

Comment: As far as I understand FileUtils is just a collection of routines which get file name(s) and perform some operations. This is not OO framework. What I expect is an abstraction of file (whether it is local, remote, astral or any other) which have some operations applicable to it such as "copy to directory", "delete", "open" etc.

Comment: FileUtils does exactly what you gave in the example above. If you need to work with remote files as well, you could probably wrap it along with Net::FTP and Net::HTTP.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. I get an instance of the file (`f = LocalFile['abc.txt']`) or create a new file (`f = LocalFile.new('def.txt', 'SOME CONTENT')`) and then rule it as I want: `f.copy_to(Directory.temporary).rewrite { |content| content.gsub("abc", "def") }.move_to(RemoteDirectory['ftp://localhost/here'])` etc. With FileUtils it looks like: `File.write(f = "abc.txt", "SOME CONTENT"); cp(f, Dir.tmpdir); File.rewrite(f) { |content| ... }; mv(f, WHAT???)`. I want to work with files like full-featured program objects, not like strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if there is a direct solution to get the type of newline based on OS, but there is the `$/` variable that holds the "input record separator". By default this will be "\n". ([Documentation here](http://ruby.activeventure.com/manual/man-1.4/variable.html#slash))

You can detect the OS and then set `$/` to the "correct" value.

To detect OS:

```
puts RUBY_PLATFORM                  # => 'i386-linux'
require 'rbconfig'
puts Config::CONFIG['target_cpu']   # => 'i386'
puts Config::CONFIG['target_os']    # => 'linux'
puts Config::CONFIG['host_cpu']     # => 'i686'
puts Config::CONFIG['host_os']      # => 'linux-gnu'
```

Also remember that when reading files, they could have a mix of various line separators - for example if a text file was edited in both Windows and Linux. Thus if you're processing files, do not depend on the "OS line seperator" exclusively.

Comment: OK, I think there is no better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open("some_temporary_file", "w") { |file| file.puts }
new_line_separator =
  File.open("some_temporary_file", "rb") { |file| file.read }
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to. In your case, I think you can just use FileUtils.

Comment: I work with very old hardware and OS which don't work with FTP correctly. I need to determine system new line separator so I could transfer the files over the broken FTP.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? In particular, how is the FTP implementation broken? Is it too broken for Net::FTP?

Comment: No, Net::FTP works fine. That's an IBM mainframe, in text mode it handles local system newline separators as record separators. And there is no possibility to perform all needed conversions locally and to transfer the file in binary mode because there is no way to put a record separator marker into the file.

Comment: So what is the problem, then?

Comment: I want to get rid of zoo of modes (text, binary, shminary etc.) and leave binary mode only. And also I still want to work with legacy hardware.

Comment: How do you propose to write a string to a binary-mode file?

Comment: As is. String and ByteArray in Ruby are the same things (at least in 1.8.7) so they will be written as is, without magic conversions like prepending "\r" to "\n", encoding in some slightly different codepage or anything else. You have bytes - you write bytes.

Comment: Oh, I see. This whole thing sort of seems like a bad idea -- you probably should work *with* Ruby's file tools if possible, not defeat them.

Comment: I'm just trying to wrap them to something more convenient, and simultaneously I'm getting rid of problems caused by legacy software (open modes and other) and hardware.