# std::endl equivalent on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cross-platform

I just can't find it.

Found you can remove them with `chomp`, but not how to create them.

Comment: simply by using `puts`?

Comment: So if I want several I have to do `puts ''` several times? That cant be the neatest way. And what if I want to include them in a string without outputting it?

Comment: well i still dont know the exact answer to your main ques, but this can be achieved by `puts "\n"*10`

Comment: @shivan `\n` isn't the line separator on all operating systems. Hence the question.

Comment: Related question / duplicate of: [System new line separator in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7995581).

Answer (score 2):

There is a [global variable `$/`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html) which represent input record separator (default to newline (`\n`)).

```
>> $/
=> "\n"
```

Methods like [`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) use this to determine input boundary.

Comment: Not exactly like [std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) ... It seems :)

Comment: Does this output "\r\n" on windows? In which case it would be enough like std::endl for my intended purposes.

Comment: @nus, According to the experiment, no, it doesn't. Writing "\n" to text output stream (for example, IO object open with `w` mode without `b`) cause "\r\n" written (in Windows).

Comment: @falsetru I'm sorry, I don't entirely understand your answer. Does `$/` translate to "\r\n" on windows like it translates to "\n" on unix?

Comment: @nus, Try `open('test.txt').write("\n")` on Windows and on Unix.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine at hand... ah, I have vm's, but then I need to install ruby...

Comment: @nus, See this: http://i.imgur.com/6cIc568.png  (upper left is on Windows, lower is on Linux)

Comment: thanks for that. So if I understand well in Ruby you can always write `"\n"` in strings within scripts and it will get translated automatically when writing to a file (and to stdout?)

Comment: @nus, Yes, as long as you write to text stream. It's same for C++.

Comment: @nus, Languages like Python provide what you want exactly: [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep). But I can't find anything exactly same in Ruby.

Comment: Whether $/ == "\r\n" is a separate question from whether File#write "\n" produces the same output as File#write $\. File#write may, as a special case, expand \n to $\, but that doesn't mean "\n" is the same as $\. The way to see if they're the same is to see if they're the same: print `$\ == "\n"`/

Comment: Please note that std::endl also flushes the stream.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you work with files in text mode (the default), Ruby itself does the translation of the operating system's end-of-line character sequences to `"\n"` in Ruby:

- When reading from a file in text mode, all line endings will appear as `"\n"`.
- When writing to a file in text mode, all newline characters `"\n"` will be written as the operating system's end-of-line character sequence.

So for all practical purposes when dealing with files in text mode, you can use `"\n"` as a constant to mean the OS-specific line ending, like std::endl.

Source: [How to make your Ruby code work on Windows PCs, section "Get your file modes right"](https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/12/14/ruby-code-on-windows/#orgheadline14).